# why doesn't this pre_get_posts code work?

Tags: wp-query, pre-get-posts

I'm trying to use pre_get_posts to modify the query so that only schools that give student discounts are displayed on the archive page. The field in question is called 'student_discount' and is a checkbox, it returns 1 if true.

when i use get_post_custom to echo the value it is '_student_discount: Array'.

This is what I have currently:

```
function show_discounts( $query ) {
   if( !is_admin() && $query->is_main_query()  && is_post_type_archive( 'job_listing' ) ) {
      $query->set( 'meta_query', array(        
       array(
          'key' => 'student_discount',
          'value' => 1,
          'compare' => '='
        ),
  ));       
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'show_discounts' );
```

UPDATE:
SInce there's confusion over the underscore....the following code:

```
$custom = get_post_custom();
foreach($custom as $key => $value) {
 echo $key.': '.$value.'<br />';
```

Produces this output:
      _company_avatar: Array
     rating: Array
     _student_discount: Array
     _nhs_discount: Array

I don't think the get_post_custom() function prepends anything. The underscore comes form the meta box I think.

Comment: The fact that `_student_discount` is an array indicates that you have multiple student_discount meta rows with value=1 matching the post ID. One cause of this could be calling `add_post_meta()` instead of `update_post_meta()` (which will update existing rows rather than inserting new ones) elsewhere in your code.

Comment: I'm just retrieving all the school and trying to filter out the ones that don't have student discount, in othere words I only want schools where 'student_discount' = 1.

Comment: You refer to the field as both `_student_discount` and `student_discount`, are you sure you are querying the correct key?

Comment: Just thought I'd offer that suggestion since having more fields than you expect can cause problems down the road. Anyway, I believe "custom" fields (à la `get_post_custom()`) prepend a `_` character to the key, but as Milo points out that's not what you're querying.

Comment: The reason some fields are prefixed with an underscore is so that those fields will be hidden from the generic Custom Fields meta box, that's how it filters those keys out for display.

Comment: isn't it the opposite? Custom Fields are prefixed with an underscore and that's how it knows to _include_ them in the meta box?

Comment: See [Hidden Custom Fields on the `add_post_meta` Codex page](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_post_meta#Hidden_Custom_Fields).

Comment: YEah I'm a little confused about the underscore as well, however I've tried both with underscore and without.

when i use get_post_custom to echo the value it is '_student_discount: Array'.

Comment: Having given up on modifying the main query I just went ahead and started from scratch w/ WP_Query, these args work in the new query:
     'meta_key'         => '_student_discount',
     'meta_value'       => '1',

they produce the desired results which is to display only schools that have student discount. I don't know why pre_get_posts isn't working for me.....those are seem correct right? Even if I use '_student_discount' it doesn't work and with the 1 in quotes. There have been some issues w/ this project, I have to assume there's something underlying this issue as the code seems good.

Comment: @acobster point seems logical to me. you should at least check `add_post_meta` & `update_post_meta` functions. and if third parameter is not supplied then consider using Boolean `false` as this param...

Comment: `get_post_custom` will always return values in an array of arrays, even if theres just a single row for that key, that's how that specific API function works. As for why `pre_get_posts` doesn't work, it helps to `var_dump($wp_query)` in the template to see how the query vars are set and the actual SQL being sent to the database, this may shed some light on why it's not working.